# Foundation reveal modal on mouseover

Tags: jquery, hover, zurb-foundation

I want to display reveal modal on mouseover

I tried this:

```
$('.hovereffect').mouseover(function() {
    console.log("hi");
    $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open'); 
});
```

Comment: did you call `$(document).foundation();` beforehand? Your `console.log` should work so it might be useful to share some of your html markup

Comment: yes i added but now issue is solved ..

Comment: previously i used  <script type="text/x-javascript">  here i used x-javascript , its older version . i remove this and it works.. thanks for ur reply.

Comment: @pratik if the issue is solved, please respond with your answer and mark it as answered so it can help others and people can see this is no longer an open question.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Codes;

```
<a href="#" class="open-first">Hover</a>
<div class='reveal-modal' id='first-modal' data-reveal>
    I'm the firstborn!
    <a class='open-second'>Click me!</a>
</div>
```

jQuery load;

```
$(document).foundation();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.open-first').hover(function(){
        $('#first-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/fatihmert/noymmdab/